# Database Shows Null Instead of Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 classes, Order and Returns. I need to have 1 return for 1 order, so far I can create a Return using a 1-many relationship which I am happy to use for testing just now, however the `ReturnId` in the `Order` class returns `null`, while both the `ReturnId` and `OrderId` in the `Return` class show the correct data. Why does the `Order` class not show the correct corresponding `ReturnId`?

Here are my classes (removed irrelevant data):

```
public partial class Order
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReturnId")]
    public returnDetails returnDetails { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class returnDetails
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ReturnId { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public System.DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

}
```

My Controllers;

```
public ActionResult ReturnsForm(int orderID)
{
    returnDetails model = new returnDetails()
    {
        OrderId = orderID
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ReturnsForm([Bind(Include = "ReturnId,OrderId,ReturnDate,Reason")] returnDetails returnDetails)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (returnDetails != null)
        {
            returnDetails.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        db.returnDetails.Add(returnDetails);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(returnDetails);
}
```

ERROR

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'returnDetails' on type 'T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.Order' is not valid. The foreign key name 'ReturnId' was not found on the dependent type 'T_shirt_Company_v3.Models.Order'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to have a 1-to-1 relationshis with foreign keys both ways as it usually involves this cycle of operations: 1. insert the first row, 2. inject the id of the first row into the second row. 3. insert the second row. 4. update the first row with the id of the second row. That step 4 there is usually not useful. Why do you need keys both ways?

Comment: I need a key to identify the Return to the Order and i need the Order to have a key to Display the Return order information. What would you recommend i do? Remove which foreign key? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Why can't you infer the retur by simply looking in the returns table if there is a row there referring to the order? Either way I'm pretty sure you have to manually edit the order row when you make a return, load it from the database, put the return id into it, and save it back.

Comment: How would I manually edit the order row @LasseV.Karlsen ?

Comment: Update it as I said, load it from the database, place the id of the return into the right property, save the changes.

Comment: Do you have fluent code that  tells EF ReturnId is a FK? Otherwise add [ForeignKey("ReturnId")] above the returnDetails navigation.

Comment: @SteveGreene from looking around that seems the best way! However I get this error when I do it, added error to question

Comment: Show your code change in the question. That should work. Only difference I have is virtual on the navigation properties, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @SteveGreene Changed my class above in the answer

Comment: You need to add the ReturnId FK field to the Order class. If it still doesn't work, take a look on the database side to see what EF did.